# Tailwind not working inside /pages directory

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Tailwind CSS not applying inside /pages folder but working inside /app folder. Any reason?

Below is the config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Folder Structure

[image]

Comment: Are you importing css also inside pages folder?

Comment: You mean global.css? No.. Its inside /app directory by default

Comment: @Nico It worked after adding import '../app/globals.css' in about.js and help.js. But if we have to manually import these css then what's the use of tailwinf.config.js?

Comment: you have to import it insie _app.js

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `**/*` to pages string, so you would get:

```
'./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}'
```

Comment: This I already tried. It's not working